# How do you center FB.login() popup in maximized browser window?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Basically, here is my js code.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
oauth: true,
channelUrl: '//www.domain.com/channel.html'
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
window.location.reload();
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
window.location.reload();
});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
function login() {
    FB.login( function(resp) {
        //not important atm}
    }, {scope: 'email, user_location, user_website'} );
}
</script>
```

A button is used to call the function login()

The code works fine. It is paired with the PHP sdk and I can authenticate just fine. The problem is the popups. When the browser window is maximized (this is consistent across IE and FF on three different computers. Addons Disabled) the popups show up properly centered vertically but to the absolute right of the screen horizontally. When the window isn't maximized, it is centered fine. The fb-root div is immediately after the body tag and everything I've tried hasn't fixed it. A previous user stated that they had fixed this issue by overriding the window.open() and editing the left attribute, however they never actually elaborated on how to do this. Since the sdk is fetched from FB, modding it isn't exactly possible. Besides, I'd prefer to make this code work.

Also, this js code used on a blank page on a testing server presented the exact same error. I think it is likely an issue with the SDK code, but I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to get this to work, hack or not, are appreciated. I've been working on this forever!

EDIT: Almost forgot. When I use the xfbml login button, the popup is fine.